# How to adjust height of table view programmatically in viewdidload

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I adjust my tableview height programmatically in viewdidload? actually I have a view in my app I want that whe view will load then uivew will be hide ang tableview height will be increase? How it can be done? I had added these lines in viewdidload but nothing happens?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 CGRect tableFrame = [tableListView frame];
tableFrame.size.height = 127; 
[tableListView setFrame:tableFrame];
}
```

Below is my screen shot I want to hide that greycolourview and want to increase my tableview height.
[image]

[image: screen shot]

Comment: What you're doing WILL change the tableView height but you will not be able to observe the change. You need to do alot more than just change the `tableView` frame in `viewDidLoad`. Besides that, you need to improve your English a bit or... explain this: "_i have a view in my app i want that whe view will load then uivew will be hide_". Also, providing code for this `UIView` will be helpful.

Comment: @staticVoidMan i had written in a hurry thats y ... will you provide some stuff for it... in the form of example? Uiview has been added through storyboard.. i am updating my question with screen shot u can see..

Comment: great, autolayout is a good start. please take a screenshot of the xcode window showing the storyboard with the `tableView` selected and the `Size Inspector` tab displayed on the right. Imo, you should have the tableView height constraint as "greater than or equal to" and a vertical spacing constraint between the `tableView` and the gray view

Comment: I had added .. u can check ..

Comment: you have not set any constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

### 1.

This should be your constraints on the `tableView`:

[image]

---

### 2.

```
//declare a constraint outlet and connect it
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintGrayViewBottom;
```

---

### 3.

This is the bottom constraint of that gray view i.e: `constraintGrayViewBottom`.
Select the bottom constraint as shown and on the right, click-drag the referencing outlet connection to the viewController and connect it to `constraintGrayViewBottom`.

[image]

---

### 4.

Handle the constraint changes as example:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    constraintGrayViewBottom.constant = -60;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: thanx i will try and let you know :)

Comment: @MishalAwan : sorry, my answer was a rushed one yesterday as i was in a hurry. i hope everything is working well for you.